# Abrupt geometry after exporting model in Maya3D

Tags: maya

hey guys I am exportin a model in maya 3D and when I open it in 3D viewer after export, the model seems to have abrupt geometry, IDK how. I encounter this thing every time I export a 3D model.
PS: I am a newbie in solid modeling.
*Before and after export screen shots attached*
[image]

[image]

HOW DO I FIX THIS ISSUE???

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of things, this is a bug within your exporter? I'm going to guess that the face with the circle hole in it, is a single polygon? If the exporter is naively triangulating the geometry *(or the viewer is naively triangulating)*, then errors like that can occur when cutting up the geo. I'd recommend selecting that particular bit of geo, and then triangulate it within Maya *(which will do it correctly)* before exporting. I'm guessing that may fix it?